# django-socketio with Celery: send to socket after async task completes in separate process

Tags: django, redis, django-celery, gevent

How can I access the result of a Celery task in my main Django application process? Or, how can I publish to an existing socket connection from a separate process?

I have an application in which users receive scores. When a score is recorded, calculations are made (progress towards goals, etc), and based on those calculations notifications are sent to interested users. The calculations may take 30s+, so to avoid sluggish UI those operations are performed in a background process via a Celery task, invoked by the post_save signal of my Score model.

Ideally the post_save signal on my Nofication model would publish a message to subscribed clients (I'm using django-socketio, a wrapper for gevent-socketio). This seems straightforward...

1. Create a Score
2. Do some calculations on the new Score instance in a background process
3. Based on those calculations, create a Notification
4. On Notification save, grab the instance and publish to subscribed clients via socket connection

However after trying the following I'm not sure this is possible:

- passing gevent's SocketIOServer instance to the callback method invoked by the task, but this requires pickling the passed object, which isn't possible
- storing the socket's session_id (different from Django's session_id) in memchache and retrieving that in the Celery task process.
- using Redis pubsub, so methods called by post_save signals on models created in a background process could simply publish to a Redis channel, but listening to chat channel in main application process (that has access to the socket connection) blocks the rest of the application.
- I've also tried spawning new threads for each Redis client, which are created for each socket subscriber. As far as I can tell this requires spawning a new gevent.greenlets.Greenlet, and gevent can't be used in multiple threads

Surely this is a solved problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show some code? I get the requirements, but your attempted implementation is not clear. What do your tasks.py and views.py look like (assuming you're using this file structure)?

Comment: when your socketio handlers startup on the server, what do they do? do they subscribe to a redis pub-sub queue? If so, are you using the redis-py gevent monkeypatch? somewhere in your ap you need to put this line: `import redis, gevent ; redis.connection.socket = gevent.socket` https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/pull/199 . the thing to understand is that gevent greenlets like socketio handlers will still block the process if you don't take care to use gevent patched sockets/filedescriptors.

Answer (score 0):

You already have django-socketio, writing a pub/sub with redis would be a pity :)

client side:

```
var socket = new io.Socket();
socket.connect();
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.subscribe({{ score_update_channel }});
});
```

server side:

```
from django_socketio import broadcast_channel
def user_score_update(user):
    return 'score_updates_user_%s' % user.pk

channel = user_score_update(user)
broadcast_channel(score_result_data, channel)
```

You need to run the broadcast on the django-socketio process; if you run it from a different process (celery worker) it will not work (channels are referenced in memory by the django-socketio process); You can solve this by wrapping it in a view and that celery will call (making a real http request) when the task is complete.